# I want to dynamically change the form of django according to user information

Tags: django

Although it is in the title, I want to change the form dynamically with django.
But now I get an error.
I can't deal with it.

I was able to get user information, but if I filter it, it will be “cannot unpack non-iterable UPRM object”.

```py
#forms.py
class RecordCreateForm(BaseModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = URC
        fields = ('UPRC','URN','UET','URT',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(RecordCreateForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['URN'].choices =  UPRM.objects.filter(user=user)
```

```py
#views.py
class RecordCreate(CreateView):
    model = URC
    form_class = RecordCreateForm
    template_name = 'records/urcform.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('person:home')  

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(RecordCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
      # get users, note: you can access request using: self.request
      kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
      return kwargs
```

```py
#models
class UPRM(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    URN = models.CharField( max_length=30,editable=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.URN

class URC(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UPRC = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    URN = models.ForeignKey(UPRM, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.UPRC
```

```
cannot unpack non-iterable UPRM object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `queryset` instead of `choices` here:

```
class RecordCreateForm(BaseModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = URC
        fields = ('UPRC','URN','UET','URT',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(RecordCreateForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['URN'].queryset = UPRM.objects.filter(user=user)
```